# The asymptotic behavior of the ratio between the largest two of $n$ i.i.d. chi-square random variables

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, st.statistics, asymptotics

My question is about the asymptotic behavior of the ratio between the largest and second largest values of $n$ independent chi-square random variables.

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be $n$ independent and identically distributed random variables with distribution $\chi_1^2$. Let $X_{(n)}$ be the largest and $X_{(n-1)}$ be the second largest of these $n$ random variables. I was wondering what is the asymptotic order of $X_{(n)}/ X_{(n-1)}$. My conjecture is that this quantity has the order of $1 + O(1/ \log n)$.

Can we show that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{X_{(n)}} {X_{(n-1)}} - 1 \asymp \frac{C}{\log n} 
\end{equation}
with high probability, where $C$ is a constant?

Comment: Set $\Phi(x)= \mathbb P(X_1 >x)$. I would say the largest values, once shifted by $\Phi^{-1}(1/n) \sim 2 \log n$, converge to some Poisson point measure, the intensity of which I have yet to compute. I would therefore go for a convergence in distribution of $X_{(n)}- X_{(n-1)}$ towards some non degenerate random variable (that is explicit once you have the intensity). This random variable would take the role of $2C$ in your expression. I'll write this down tomorrow if nobody has.

Comment: On this kind of convergence of extreme values, you may check the lecture notes by Anton Bovier https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Anton_Bovier/lecture-notes/extreme.pdf

Comment: if you replace $\chi_1^2$  by $\chi_2^2$ you have exponentials and as you have the inverse cumulant it should be easy to decide, then you have the issue of getting a good grid on the inverse cumulant of the  $\chi_1^2$.

Comment: @michael Good remark, the ordered statistics of the exponential random variable are indeed very simple :-)  With that choice it is quick to realize your $C$ should be random.  @ Steve:  $X_{(n)}/2\log(n)$ converges in probability to $1$ and (to be checked) $X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)}$ weakly converges to an exponential with parameter $1/2$. I can give more details if you need.

Comment: Thanks @micheal  and @Olivier! Your remarks are very helpful. I think I can solve that using the fact that $X_{(n)} - X_{(n-1)} $ converges to an exponential distribution.

Comment: @Olivier  I found it a bit difficult to show that $X_{(n)}- X_{(n-1)}$ converges to an exponential random variable in distribution. could you please elaborate more on this? I know how to write the density as an integration, but I don't know how to do approximation to get the limit. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reading the chapter "point processes of extremes" in the lecture notes that I mentioned? You should find what you need around p.79. Perhaps there is a shortcut to prove the convergence of the spacing of the two largest values without proving the convergence of the full front though...